# How to know or calculate empty or blank cells on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a big list of products on google sheets about 900 rows.
And on these rows is the information about every product, when customers buy one I put the id of the product in ID product column.

Now I want to now how many cells are blank or empty I can't Calculate manually every 900 cells.

How can I create a function that helps me calculate empty cells on your list on google sheets?

Comment: If you drop your homework here either complete hide it or tell us that it is ( "fine read the text above " and "a function help you to calculate empty cells on your list on google sheets" in the original text). A question (as in a sentence) in English has a particular grammatical form and ends in a question mark. Stating what you want is not the same as asking a question. Please improve your post with code that you have, and what goes wrong. It already states what you need to achieve.

Comment: look @Anthon when i want to post my question the editor tell me the text is too short and i duplicate the question to post it successfully 
do you understand what i mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google sheets has a formula for that.

```
  =COUNTBLANK(range)
```